# "ob mit oder ohne Null"

Tags: grammatical-case, definite-article

Should we add an article and, if so, in which case:

> Für Demonstrationszwecke ist es in diesem Beispiel irrelevant, dass wir die natürlichen Zahlen – ob mit oder ohne ***[die/der]*** Null – als zu speichernde Elemente unseres Containers wählten; es können genauso gut Monster, Nymphomanen, Planeten oder sonstige Objekte des zu programmierenden Spiels sein.

Do we need an article, and, if so, which one and why?

The context of the sentence contains neither 0 nor Null.

Answer (score 5):

There's no article needed, but if you use one, it has to be **ohne die Null**, because the preposition *ohne* requires the accusative.

Comment: What's the difference between "mit oder ohne Null" and "mit oder ohne die Null"?

Comment: There's no difference in meaning. Using the definite article adds a pointing finger to the *Null*.

Comment: Thank you. The phrase "pointing finger" is a little bit too figurative to me: we have no figers in the typed text, and we have a freedom not to use fingers while speaking. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: There are true demonstrative pronouns in German, these are *dieser/dieses/dieses*, *jener/jene/jenes*, *der-/die-/dasjenige*, *solcher/solche/solches*. You can visualize these as a finger pointing to an object in front of you, an object further away, an object in a group, a matching object. The definite article *der/die/das* has such a demonstrative function, too. It's a mild one, less pointy than the other demonstrative pronouns.

Comment: Oh, in this case, since the Null is unique and is not an object in the context on the sentence, technically speaking, pointing to the Null wouldn't make that much sense.

Comment: Yes, that's why the article is not needed. There are derived meanings of *Null* however: *Die/Diese Nullen haben schon wieder verloren.* (*Die/Diese Nullen* is a derogative for the members of your home team here.)

Comment: If I get your explanation right, then "die" would be even wrong in the sense that it would convey an unintended meaning.

Comment: No, it's not wrong. *Die Null* is only pointing to the Null as a special case, not saying it's a special Null from a selection of Nulls. That latter meaning needs a real demonstrative pronoun as *diese* or *jene* etc.

Comment: Ich muss sagen, _mit oder ohne **der** Null_ klingt für mich wesentlich natürlicher als mit Akkusativ. Mag aber ein Helvetismus sein?

Answer (score 4):

### Ohne Artikel

Im mathematischen Kontext verwendet man in gesprochenen Sätzen oder im Fließtext "die natürlichen Zahlen ohne Null".

Dies wird auch in [der Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat%C3%BCrliche_Zahl) so angewandt:

> Für die Menge der **natürlichen Zahlen ohne Null**...

### Mit Artikel

Im selben Wikipedia-Artikel wird allerdings auch eine Gegenüberstellung gemacht:

> [Die Menge der natürlichen Zahlen] umfasst entweder die positiven ganzen Zahlen (also **ohne die 0**) oder die nichtnegativen ganzen Zahlen (also **inklusive der 0**)

Bei dieser Gegenüberstellung möchte der Autor speziell auf das (Nicht-)Vorhandensein der Null hinweisen.

---

### Persönliche Meinung

Im Kontext der Frage würde ich persönlich "ob mit oder ohne Null" **ohne Artikel** schreiben.